# How to compile and run PApplet

Tags: java, processing

I am working on a project using the Unfolding map library, which requires the application to be a PApplet.  However I'm having trouble compiling and running such a program on the command line using javac (it works in Eclipse).  Here's what I have right now:

**Directory Structure**

```
.
├── build/
├── lib/
│   └── core.jar
├── Makefile
└── src/
    └── unfolding/
        └── Unfolding.java
```

**Makefile**

```
all:
    javac -classpath .:lib/core.jar -sourcepath src -d build src/**/*.java
    cd build
    java -classpath .:../lib/core.jar unfolding.Unfolding
```

**src/unfolding/Unfolding.java**

```
package unfolding;

import processing.core.*;

public class Unfolding extends PApplet {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PApplet.main(new String[] { "unfolding.Unfolding" });
    }

    public void setup() {
        size(800, 600, OPENGL);
    }

    public void draw() {
        background(0);
    }
}
```

When I run the Makefile, I get the following error:

> Could not find or load main class unfolding.Unfolding

I've read quite a lot about this (mainly [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18093929/2016305)), but as far as I can tell, I'm doing everything correctly.  What else am I missing here?

I'm using Java 1.8 and the core.jar is from Processing 3.

Also note that while my class is called Unfolding, I haven't actually started incorporating the Unfolding library yet, so that is irrelevant to the issue.

Comment: Are you able to run the program from eclipse ?

Comment: Yes, a 800x600 black window appears

Comment: How are you running from command prompt ?

Comment: I type `make`, so the commands in the makefile are run.  It builds successfully but the error occurs when run

Comment: I think the build folder contains classes, so you have to run from build folder.

Comment: Oh right, I had a "cd build" in the Makefile that I missed when copying it over.  It is updated now

Comment: Try splitting it up into multiple steps so you know which step fails. Does compiling by itself work?

Comment: Yeah compiling works, running doesn't

Comment: Ok, now try to run from build folder

Comment: That's what I had been doing.  It turns out I had to run the PApplet class and pass my class as an argument (see my answer below).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the issue was I had to run a PApplet and pass the main class as an argument.  So like this:

```
java -classpath .:../lib/core.jar processing.core.PApplet unfolding.Unfolding
```